# Prove: if x^n = x, then prove that x + x = 0 for additive identity 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer.

Under a ring, suppose for any $x$, $x^n = x$. Then for any $x$, $x + x = 0$ for additive identity $0$.

How is this proven?

The case when $n$ is even is rather easy:

$x^n = (-x)^n$ so $x = -x$

However I am not able to find a proof for a general $n$.

Comment: Is it true? I think $\mathbb{Z} / 5\mathbb{Z}$ with $n=5$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Other counterexamples would include $n = 1$ or $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $n = p$ for every odd prime $p$. So I don't see how this would ever be considered true, unless of course if $n$ is even (note that in this case, you still need another proof, yours is not yet complete).

Comment: @DirkLiebhold What's incomplete about the proof for even $n$?

Comment: @Adayah On second thought, nothing. I read it wrong the first time, so it is ok as it is, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. The In $\mathbb Z_3$, you have $2^3=2$ and $2+2=1\neq 0$.

Comment: But in your example $n=3$, right?

Comment: @Adayah oh yeah, right.

Comment: Thank you, I was scratching my head trying to prove it for a couple of minutes there.